# How to set a unique key in v-for loop when iterating over a range?

Tags: key, vuejs3, v-for

I am trying to set a key for each component generated by a `v-for` loop.
I would like to click on a button and generate a row of Bootstrap columns after every click.

I went for a `v-for` approach despite having no array to loop over, so I suppose a key is required as otherwise, an error would pop up.

This is the row before I click on the submit button :

[image]

And the result after I click :

[image]

My goal is to generate a new row with empty cards with original styling.
Right now it seems that it is copying the state of the previous row.

**App.vue:**

```html
<ul id="guessList" class="list-unstyled">
    <li v-for="guess in guessIDs" :key="guess">
        <div :id="guess" class="row justify-content-center align-self-center mb-3">
            <MoveGroup v-for="n in lengthGuess"
            :key="`${guess}_move_group${n}`">{{ n }}</MoveGroup>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I don't understand why this code doesn't generate a unique key every time.
The guess part of the key corresponds to the element taken from an array containing strings representing IDs.

Here's the vue app :

**App.vue**:

```js
    export default {
    name: 'boardApp',
    data() {
        return {
            lengthGuess: 0,
            opening: [],
            movesPlayed: [],
            remainingGuesses: 5,
            guessIDs: ['guess1']
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setMode(value) {
            this.lengthGuess = value
            const self = this
            const fetch_url = document.querySelector('#app').getAttribute(
                'fetch-url')
            return fetch(fetch_url + '?move_count=' + value)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((result) => {
                self.opening = result.moves
            })
        },
        storeMove(move) {
            this.movesPlayed.push(move)
        },
        undoMove() {
            this.movesPlayed.pop()
        },
        clearMoves() {
            this.movesPlayed = []
        },
        checkGuess() {
            if (this.movesPlayed.length < this.lengthGuess * 2) {
                alert('You must play more moves.')
                return
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < this.lengthGuess * 2; i++) {
                const move = this.movesPlayed[i]
                const answer = this.opening[i]
                const guessNum = 6 - this.remainingGuesses
                const moveCard = document.querySelectorAll(
                    `#guess${guessNum} .card`)[i]
                if (move == answer) {
                    moveCard.classList.remove('bg-dark')
                    moveCard.classList.add('bg-success')
                }
                else if (this.opening.find((_str) => _str == move)) {
                    moveCard.classList.remove('bg-dark')
                    moveCard.classList.add('bg-warning')
                }
            }
            this.remainingGuesses--
            this.guessIDs.push(`guess${6 - this.remainingGuesses}`)
        },
    },
    components: { MoveGroup, ModalInstructions, ChessBoard }
```

Where am I going wrong here ?

Thanks !

Edit:
Here's the code for the MoveGroup component:

**Components/move-group.vue**

```html
<template>                                                                                                                
    <div class="d-flex col">                                                                                              
        <span class="mx-1" style="font-size:1.5rem; font-weight:bold;">                                                   
            <slot/>.                                                                                                      
        </span>                                                                                                           
        <div>                                                                                                             
            <div class="card bg-dark" style="width:4rem; height:4rem;">                                                   
                <div class="card-body row">                                                                               
                    <p class="card-text align-middle align-self-center text-center text-light">                           
                    </p>                                                                                                  
                </div>                                                                                                    
            </div>                                                                                                        
        </div>                                                                                                            
        <div class="col-1"></div>                                                                                         
        <div>                                                                                                             
            <div class="card bg-dark" style="width:4rem; height:4rem;">                                                   
                <div class="card-body row">                                                                               
                    <p class="card-text align-middle align-self-center text-center text-light">                           
                    </p>                                                                                                  
                </div>                                                                                                    
            </div>                                                                                                        
        </div>                                                                                                            
    </div>                                                                                                                
</template>
```

Comment: Try to fix the first v-for key with only `guess` or with another logic to produce an unique key, because there isn't `id` key inside `guessIDs` and you are setting it as `:key` for the first `v-for`. And at this part ```:key=":key="`${guess}_move_group${n}`">{{ n }}</MoveGroup>``` there is a typo probably and should be something like this ```:key="`${guess}_move_group${n}`">{{ n }}</MoveGroup>```

Comment: That's my bad here, I should correct the original question, these typos aren't in the file right now and it still doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct DOM manipulation is a trap!!! in Vue. That's why many javascript libraries needs an adaptation to SPA frameworks.

You should refactor the CSS changes to bind the component with probably props. Here's is an example, but the logic is not right. So you need to adapt as your needs.

So, avoid DOM manipulation and let Vue take care of it, for more info about why this happens: [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html)

```js
const MoveGroup = {
  name: "MoveGroup",
  template: document.querySelector("#move-group").innerHTML,
  props: ["active"]
};

const App = {
  name: "App",
  template: document.querySelector("#app-template").innerHTML,
  data() {
    return {
      lengthGuess: 2,
      opening: ["e5", "c2"],
      movesPlayed: ["e5", "c2"],
      remainingGuesses: 5,
      guessIDs: ["guess1"],
    };
  },
  components: {
    MoveGroup,
  },
  methods: {
    addToGuessIds() {
      this.remainingGuesses--;
      this.guessIDs = [...this.guessIDs, `guess${6 - this.remainingGuesses}`];
    },
  }
};

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app');
```

```html
<template id="move-group">
    <div class="d-flex col">
    <span class="mx-1" style="font-size: 1.5rem; font-weight: bold">
      <slot></slot>
    </span>
    <div>
      <div
        :class="['card', active ? 'bg-success' : 'bg-dark']"
        style="width: 4rem; height: 4rem"
      >
        <div class="card-body row">
          <p
            class="card-text align-middle align-self-center text-center text-light"
          ></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div>
      <div
        :class="['card', active ? 'bg-success' : 'bg-dark']"
        style="width: 4rem; height: 4rem"
      >
        <div class="card-body row">
          <p
            class="card-text align-middle align-self-center text-center text-light"
          ></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="app-template">
   <div>
    <ul id="guessList" class="list-unstyled">
      <li v-for="(guess, index) in guessIDs" :key="guess">
        <div
          :id="guess"
          class="row justify-content-center align-self-center mb-3"
        >
          <move-group
            v-for="n in lengthGuess"
            :key="`${guess}_move_group${n}`"
            :active="index !== guessIDs.length - 1"
            >{{ n }}
            </move-group>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button @click="addToGuessIds">Add</button>
  </div>
</template>

<div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: I've made the modifications but my problem remains the same though.
At least I know the issue isn't the key I'm giving to the component.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. If you can, post more about MoveGroup component. Perhaps that's the problem

Comment: Updated! That's the way to go!